# Find and replace to remove the icon in all my forms

Tags: regex, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, replace

I'm using Visual Studio, and I would like to remove the icon in all the forms on my code. The icon is embedded in the resx files, so I used the following regular expression to find the icon, then I used find and replace:

```
\<data name=\"\$this\.Icon\".+\n(.*\n)*^.+rEE=\n(.*\n)(.*\n)
```

The icon is present in the resX files with the following code:

```
      <data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>
           AAABAAgAICAQAAEABADoAgAAhgAAABAQEAABAAQAKAEAAG4DAAAwMAAAAQAIAKgOAACWBAAAICAAAAEA
           ...
           rEGAAaxBgAGsQYABrEHAAaxBwAOsQeAHrEHgH6xB+D+sQf//rEE=
        </value>
      </data>
```

It works, but the performance is VERY bad. How can I find a faster regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- find data tags which have an attribute of `name=$this.icon`
- avoid some of the sticky problems with using regex for reading non regular markup languages

`<data\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sname="\$this\.Icon")(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?>(?:(?!<\/data>)[\s\S])*?<\/data>`

[image]

## Example

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/FqdOI8H27X

**Sample Text**

Note the first data tag has some difficult edge cases

```
<data onmouseover=' name="$this.Icon" ; funReplace("</data>", name) ; ' type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>
           AAABAAgAICAQAAEABADoAgAAhgAAABAQEAABAAQAKAEAAG4DAAAwMAAAAQAIAKgOAACWBAAAICAAAAEA
           ...
           rEGAAaxBgAGsQYABrEHAAaxBwAOsQeAHrEHgH6xB+D+sQf//rEE=
        </value>
      </data>
<data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>
           AAABAAgAICAQAAEABADoAgAAhgAAABAQEAABAAQAKAEAAG4DAAAwMAAAAQAIAKgOAACWBAAAICAAAAEA
           ...
           rEGAAaxBgAGsQYABrEHAAaxBwAOsQeAHrEHgH6xB+D+sQf//rEE=
        </value>
      </data>
```

**Matches**

```
[0] => <data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
       AAABAAgAICAQAAEABADoAgAAhgAAABAQEAABAAQAKAEAAG4DAAAwMAAAAQAIAKgOAACWBAAAICAAAAEA
       ...
       rEGAAaxBgAGsQYABrEHAAaxBwAOsQeAHrEHgH6xB+D+sQf//rEE=
    </value>
  </data>
```